# A better alternative than &nbsp; for showing empty HTML table cells?

Tags: html, css, html-table

## WARNING - THIS QUESTION IS OVER 10 YEARS OLD. TODAY THIS IS NO LONGER A PROBLEM. THE QUESTION REMAINS FOR HISTORICAL REASONS.

It's a classic problem - when you have an empty table cell the browser doesn't render borders around it. There are also two well-known workarounds. One is to place an `&nbsp;` in the table cell; the other is to use the `empty-cells:show` CSS property.

Unfortunately both have drawbacks. `&nbsp;` is kind of ugly when it comes to selecting text and copy-pasting it. You get a lot of spaces where there shouldn't be any, perhaps even with an exotic Unicode character. `empty-cells:show` should address exactly this problem, but unfortunately it only works properly in IE starting with version 8 (and then only in standards-compliant mode). It can be made to work in other versions by also specifying `border-collapse: collapse`, but sometimes this is what is NOT desired. In my case I have a fairly complex table and it relies on `border-collapse:separate` and would otherwise create quite a messy CSS/HTML soup.

So what are other things that you might put in a table cell that would make IE draw the borders yet not be visible or copyable? For all other browsers the `empty-cells:show` already does the trick, so I really just need to fool IE.

Answer (score 13):

You can also put invisible br element:

```
<td><br style="visibility:hidden"></td>
```

It is ridiculous amount of unnecessary code, but it makes the trick - no additional text added yet cell is displayed.

Note that `<br/>` is invalid HTML syntax according to the official specifications http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-BR. It is valid XHTML syntax however.

Comment: Of course you can define a CSS class .e{visibility:hidden} and write <br class="e" />, or, alternatively, if don't have other meaningful br elements in the table, define a style "table br {visibility:hidden}"

Comment: How does <br style="visibility:hidden"/> differ from <br> ? Both allocate the space and both display nothing else.

Comment: Try selecting table cell contents in IE6 with visibility set to hidden and without it. When it is set cell does not seem to get selected (at least visualy). This is exactly what the person who asked question wanted.

Comment: Hmm yes, I see. Thanks. Not quite *exactly* what the OP asked though, as the carriage returns are still copied even though they're not visible when selected.

Answer (score 3):

You can show the cells with this CSS code. I successfully tested it in Safari and Firefox. I guess it works in other browsers as well.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  empty-cells: show;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
td:empty:after {
  content: '.';
  color: transparent;
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* alternate background */

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This question was asked 5 years ago and the problem was specifically IE7 that didn't respect `empty-cells:show`. :P

Comment: This thread poped up on google when I was looking for a solution. `empty-cells: show` does neither work in Safari nor in Firefox when all cells of a row are empty. I'm sure it will help others.

Comment: Maybe, but I doubt it. :( The question is about something completely different.

Comment: this is a much better solution than adding HTML elements. it worked for me on Chrome, FireFox and Safari on Mac. however, the problem i was encountering involved only single table cells, not entire table rows filled with only empty cells.

Comment: It breaks editing capability on conteneditable tables on ff 42.