# Why is `&nbsp;` required in HTML description lists

Tags: html, css

I often use the following code to create a table without using HTML table tag.  Maybe I should just start using the table tag, but that isn't the question.

If `<dd>` tag is empty, the next `<dt>` tag will not float left and be on it's own line, butt adding `&nbsp;` to the `<dd>` tag makes it do so.

Why is `&nbsp;` needed, and how can the CSS be changed so it need not be?

http://jsfiddle.net/bx7sLcx0/

```
dl.table dt, dl.table dd {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
}
dl.table dt {
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
}

<dl class="table">
    <dt>Title</dt><dd>bla</dd>
    <dt>Title</dt><dd>bla</dd>
    <dt>Title</dt><dd></dd>
    <dt>Title</dt><dd>bla</dd>
    <dt>Title</dt><dd>bla</dd>
    <dt>Title</dt><dd>&nbsp;</dd>
    <dt>Title</dt><dd>bla</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dd`, like other block elements, collapse if they have no content. However, you can give them a `height` (or `min-height`), a `border`, or give them content using a `::before` or `::after` pseudo-element. You'll see that they are not really gone, they just have a zero height by default if there is no content.

```css
dl.table dt, 
dl.table dd {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
}
dl.table dt {
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
}

dl.table dd { border: 1px solid blue; min-height: 1em;}
}
```

```html
<dl class="table">
    <dt>Title</dt><dd>bla</dd>
    <dt>Title</dt><dd>bla</dd>
    <dt>Title</dt><dd></dd>
    <dt>Title</dt><dd>bla</dd>
    <dt>Title</dt><dd></dd>
    <dt>Title</dt><dd>&nbsp;</dd>
    <dt>Title</dt><dd>bla</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

The empty elements won't be generated and so they have no size. You can fix this via CSS when setting a min-height:

```
dt {
    clear: left;
}

dt, 
dd {
    min-height: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you are floating the dt elements so the dd without any content is not occupying any page real estate hence why the next dt element is appearing next to the other. A quick fix is just to add clear:left to your td element in the css.

```
dl.table dt {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Craig.  Think the min-height is also required.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/emptycells.html) is a nice post about it. And also, stackpost [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789372/a-better-alternative-than-nbsp-for-showing-empty-html-table-cells).

Comment: In case the links break in the future, it would be useful to include relevant excerpts in your answer.