# Displaying empty table cells without &nbsp;

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table of empty cells on which I'm attaching Javascript to toggle a class, so I just need to give them a height and width. The problem is when I create the table, while it has padding, I can't get it to maintain it's height. I'm trying to avoid using `&nbsp;` as when I do, it creates the mouseover of highlighting text, and multiple clicks on the box can select the text.

Looking online, `empty-cells: show;` comes up as the constant answer, but it doesn't seem to keep the height. I've considered doing it as a series of inline-block divs, but then borders become messy, as the borders don't collapse.

I literally just have an empty table

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; empty-cells: show;">
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 1.3em; padding: 4px 6px;"></td>
        <td style="height: 1.3em; padding: 4px 6px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I feel like this is an old HTML problem, and I'm missing some simple answer.

I had seen the question that was suggested as the duplicate, but as the answer there is 5 years old, I thought there must be something more modern for addressing this problem. If there isn't, I guess the `visibility` trick is the way to go.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A better alternative than &nbsp; for showing empty HTML table cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789372/a-better-alternative-than-nbsp-for-showing-empty-html-table-cells)

Comment: @AVI As I mentioned in my question, `empty-cells` doesn't seem to solve my problem. As the question was asked 7 years ago and the answer last edited 5 years ago, I thought maybe there's a more up to date solution.

Comment: You haven't mentioned why you don't want to use nbsp;

Comment: If you don't show your ([mcve]) code we can't solve your code problems.

Comment: I added an explanation for nbsp; sorry for not including it from the start. And I did add an example, but as this is more a theory question, didn't think to add it to start.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific minimum height that you want? If so, you can do something like this:

```
table tr td:first-child::after {
   content: "";
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   min-height: 60px;
}
```

Source code from omelniz originally posted here: [Can I use a min-height for table, tr or td?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432092/can-i-use-a-min-height-for-table-tr-or-td)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

For `<th>` and `<td>` :

```
th:empty::before,td:empty::before{content:'\00a0';visibility:hidden}
```

For `<td>` only :

```
td:empty::before{content:'\00a0';visibility:hidden}
```

Description:

`'\00a0'` is code for single space

`visibility:hidden` to hide that single space